# How to compose a variable name from a macro in C++?

Tags: c++, macros

How to compose a variable name from a macro in C++?
For example:

```
#define PREFIX p_
#define VAR_NAME #PREFIX#name
```

So, `VAR_NAME` must be exposed as `p_name`. Is it possible?

Comment: You're probably looking for the [`##` preprocessor operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators).

Comment: @G.M., how? `#define VAR_NAME ##PREFIX##name`? it's doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to jump through some hoops with the preprocessor to do this:

```
#define CONCAT_(a, b) a##b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_(a, b)

#define PREFIX p_
#define VAR_NAME CONCAT(PREFIX, name)

int VAR_NAME;
```

`CONCAT_` combines text

`CONCAT` evaluates macros before combining them